# Sum columns or new column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

For a ranking system (in a database with ten thousands of users) I want to rank users by the sum of three columns: e.g. `Points_A`, `Points_B` and `Points_C`. I would like to know what would be a better option:

- Every time the ranking page is visited, calculate the ranking of the users by summing all the columns and order by the sum
- Create a new column `Points_total` with the sum of the three columns (I update the total each time one of the other columns gets updated) and order the query by this `Points_total`.

The ranking page could be requested multiple times each second, so performance is really important. Is the second option faster or not recommended?

Comment: best bet is to try it the easier way (w/o storing the sum) and see if performance is *acceptable*.  Not which is better, cause no matter how much better the harder way is, say, even if it's 1000s of times faster,  like it takes latency from 120 ms to less than a femtosecond, 120 ms is more than fast enough for a page to load.  i.e., performance is really important only if it dramatically affects the user experience.

Answer (score 3):

As of MySQL 5.7.6 you can create generated columns, which gives you the ability to store a **virtual** value based on other values in other columns in your table.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    Points_A INT,
    Points_B INT,
    Points_C INT,
    Points_total INT AS (Points_A + Points_B + Points_C)
);
```

Generated column definitions have this syntax:

> col_name data_type [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression)
>         [VIRTUAL | STORED] [UNIQUE [KEY]] [COMMENT comment]
>         [[NOT] NULL] [[PRIMARY] KEY]

You can decide to use `VIRTUAL` or `STORED` (depends on what you need).

As of MySQL 5.7.8 you can also add [INDEXes on virtual columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html), so in your case - this is exactly what you are looking for (this way the values in the column are indexed).

> If you are using MySQL older than 5.7.8 and the ranking page is being accessed many times - I would suggest you to same the calculated value in specific column and add an index on that column.

Comment: If the OP has tens of thousands of users, then an index is probably needed for the requirements.

Comment: Caution:  At some point (millions of users?) the cost of repeatedly updating the index will be prohibitive.  The cost is essentially "delete a row from a BTree (the index) and reinsert it somewhere else".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought.  Rather than taking costly action on every change in ranking, see if this complicated approach might be better:

But first, this depends on `Points` only increasing, never decreasing.  It also assumes that you only need the top 10 ranks. and don't care about discovering "I am ranked 7654 out of 10000")

Set up a Trigger (or app code) that reacts whenever a rank is increased.  It adds the points together and checks against a threshold.  If below the 10th-ranked value, do nothing further.

If higher, then perform the `SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 10` to get the new "top 10" and store the result in a separate table.  Also, update the threshold.

The *possible* benefits:

- This separate table is what is accessed 'multiple times each second', but the main table need not be.
- Doing less work most(?) of the time.  (But doing more work on things that get upvoted a lot.)
- Segregating the rank-display table (10 rows) from the main table (10K rows), thereby decreasing lock contention.
- This *may* be a use case for the Query cache:

  - Turn it on,
  - set `query_cache_size = 20M` (not too big),
  - `query_cache_type = DEMAND`
  - add `SQL_CACHE` to the rank `SELECT`; add `SQL_NO_CACHE` to most other `SELECTs`.

If you need more than just one page of the "top 10", considering saving the "top 50".  For the first 5 pages, the new table suffices.  For page 6 and beyond, do it the hard way (scan the 10K-row table).  Hopefully, this will be rare enough to still be an advantage.